# namenode and mapred is not starting

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop on ubuntu 13.10,but when i start all the daemons using "start-all.sh". Only the secondary namenode is starting. And this is shown on screen.

```
starting namenode, logging to /home/shubham/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-shubham-namenode-shubham-pc.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/shubham/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-shubham-datanode-shubham-pc.out
localhost: secondarynamenode running as process 9580. Stop it first.
starting jobtracker, logging to /home/shubham/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-shubham-jobtracker-shubham-pc.out
Error: Could not find or load main class export
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /home/shubham/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-shubham-tasktracker-shubham-pc.out
```

Comment: What is in the log files? Check namenode, datanode logs.